# Growth functions of finite group - computation, typical behaviour, surveys?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, experimental-mathematics, cayley-graphs

Looking on the growth function for Rubik's group and symmetric group, one sees rather different behaviour:

Rubik's growth in LOG scale (see [MO322877](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322877)):
[image: Rubik's growth in LOG scale]

S_n n=9 growth and nice fit by normal distribution (NOT log scale):
[image: S_n n=9 growth and nice fit by normal distribution (NOT log scale)]

As usually growth function of $n$ - is number of elements which can be represented by product of  $n$ generators and cannot by less number.
For symmetric group we take standard generators - adjacent permutations (and so code below uses the fact that length equals to inversion number), for Rubik's group also standard generators - see [MO322877](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322877/number-of-positions-of-rubiks-cube-grows-with-multiplier-13-with-the-distance). The rough explanation behind such difference is that S_n and its generators is more like an abelian group, while generators of Rubiks group behave like a free group up to certain order and than cutted by relations of quite a long length. 
For abelian groups like $(Z/2Z)^n$ grows corresponds to normal distribution by the most classical central limit theorem ([see bean machine video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine)), normal distribution approximation often happens for various metrics on $S_n$ - see 
[MO320497](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320497/metrics-on-finite-groups-and-generalizations-of-central-limit-theorems-for-balls?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Informal question** what can a be a something like a typical growth for finite groups ? For example take "small group library of GAP" what is typical there ?

**Question 2** Can computer algebra systems like GAP or MAGMA compute such a growth for finite groups and given set of generators ? At least for "small group library" ? What algorithms are used ?

I understand there is huge literature on Cayley graphs of groups
e.g. [Harald A. Helfgott,BAMS, 2015, Growth in groups: ideas and perspectives](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2015-52-03/S0273-0979-2015-01475-8/home.html) (see also [MO102737](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102737/diameter-of-symmetric-group)), still I wonder:

**Question 3** What are some other nice surveys which concentrates on finite groups Cayley graphs and growth functions ?

PS

Here is old discussion of similar spirit:
[What relationship, if any, is there between the diameter of the Cayley graph and the average distance between group elements?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61443/what-relationship-if-any-is-there-between-the-diameter-of-the-cayley-graph-and?rq=1)
what is "typical" relation between diameter median - taking Rubik's cube and S_n as examples

PSPS

Here is Python3 code for  $S_9$ growth calculation and normal fit. (One can use https://colab.research.google.com/ for free - you even do not need to install anything on your comp - use browser and code runs on google's servers:

```
def inversion(permList): # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579051-get-the-inversion-number-of-a-permutation/
    """
    Description - This function returns the number of inversions in a
                  permutation.
    Preconditions - The parameter permList is a list of unique positve numbers.

    Postconditions - The number of inversions in permList has been returned.

    Input - permList : list
    Output - numInversions : int
    """
    if len(permList)==1:
        return 0
    else:
        numInversion=len(permList)-permList.index(max(permList))-1
        permList.remove(max(permList))
        return numInversion+inversion(permList)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 

import scipy
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np


# Get all permutations  # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/
# using library function 
from itertools import permutations # import lib
n = 9
lst = range(1,(n+1) ) # =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..., n]
perm = permutations(lst) # all n! permutations are here

list_i = [] # Store all inversion numbers here 
v = np.zeros(int( n*(n+1)/2) )  # histogram for inversion numbers here
start_time = time.time()
for p in list(perm): # Loop over permutations
  inv_count = inversion(list(p))  
  v[inv_count] += 1 
  list_i.append(inv_count) # 

print('n=',n, time.time() - start_time  , 'seconds passed' )
print('Mean' , np.mean( list_i), 'Std ', np.std( list_i) )    

y = v / np.sum(v)  # normalize histogram
plt.plot(y,'*-',label = 'Length Distribution')

# Fit by normal part:
dist = getattr(scipy.stats, 'norm')
param = dist.fit(np.array(list_i) ) # https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/distribution-fitting-with-scipy.html
x = np.linspace(0,int( n*(n+1)/2),int( n*(n+1)/2)+1)
# fitted distribution
pdf_fitted = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,loc=param[0],scale=param[1]) # https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/distribution-fitting-with-scipy.html
plt.plot(x,pdf_fitted,'d-', label = 'Fit by normal')
plt.legend()
plt.title('S_n n= '+str(n) )
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you make experiments, you might try with $S_n$ with a random pair. Indeed, random pairs are generically generating, and the behavior for growth is known to be very different from "obvious" generating pairs such that the pair $\{(12),(123\dots n)\}$, notably they have a smaller diameter. (Still I don't know if for such a given group as $S_9$ the "generic" behavior is already preponderant.)

Comment: @YCor thank you ! So from your comment and reading JSE and Tao https://mathoverflow.net/a/61495/10446 it seems that randomly chosen elements should give something like an expander graph and that should be different from standard generators of S_n picture. It is interesting whether properties mentioned by JSE fullfils for Rubik's cube...