# Distance distribution for Cayley graphs of the fintie Heisenberg groups H3(Z/nZ) approaches Gaussian for large "n"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, finite-groups, cayley-graphs, heisenberg-groups

I wonder several questions about Cayley graphs of finite Heisenberg groups H3(Z/nZ).

**Question 1:** do we know the diameter dependence on "n", at least for the standard choice of generators ? What about some other choices ?

**Question 2:** Is it true/known that the distance distribution approaches the Gaussian for large "n" ? What are the m,sigma ? What is the rate of the convergence ?  (For standard generators and is something known for other choices of generators ? ).

Motivation: As far as I understand for generic non-commutative groups/their generators we can expect exponential growth at least to nearby diameter, while for commutative-like the the distribution would be Gaussian like with the mode of the distribution placed quite far from the diameter. See examples e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/324003/10446) .

**Question 3:** Are there some general results stating that for some class on say nilpotent groups, for their finite quotients, the distance distribution would tend to Gaussian ? (For example unitriangular/related matrices over Z/nZ).

---

PS

Here are some simulation for Heisenberg groups for standard and a bit-bit non-standard generators. One can find some more background/info at the head of the linked notebook.

Heisenberg group with two standard generators <x,y>
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/santa23-growth-heisenberg-group?scriptVersionId=158703270&cellId=16
[image]

Heisenberg group with three generators (standard <x,y> and their commutator "z")
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/santa23-growth-heisenberg-group?scriptVersionId=158703218&cellId=16
[image]

Comment: Later remarks - about Guassian - it might not be correct - for abelian groups (Z/n)^d we get normal distribution for large "d" , but not "n". So here probably we get normal distribution also for Heisenberg groups of rank "d" for large "d".  While H3( Z/n)  for finite "n" the beginning of the sequence is the same as for H3(Z) , which generation function is -  RATIOANL function https://oeis.org/A063810 : 1, 4, 12, 36, 82, 164, 294....